# How can I solve postgresql problem after deleting wal files?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, backup, checkpoint, write-ahead-logging

I turned the archive_mode on on my postgresql configuration for testing a backup server . And since the wal files took lots of disk space, after my test I turned it off and also deleted the wal files. When I tried to restart postgresql I got the following error.

```
 root@hooshang:/etc/postgresql/9.1/main# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-10-15 15:51:53 IRST
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  could not open file "pg_xlog/00000001000007DC00000037" (log file 2012, segment 55): No such file or directory
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  could not open file "pg_xlog/00000001000007DC00000029" (log file 2012, segment 41): No such file or directory
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  startup process (PID 17467) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
 2014-10-16 13:15:28 IRST LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have corrupted your database by manually deleting files from within the data directory. *Never* delete files from within the data directory manually.

### Safely removing WAL

If you want to remove WAL, either let the server do it at `CHECKPOINT` time, or [use `pg_archivecleanup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgarchivecleanup.html). Note that the server will remove WAL is no longer needs automatically, unless:

- `archive_mode` is on, but [`archive_command`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html) is failing, so the server keeps on retrying the archive attempts until they succeed or the admin intervenes;
- It's still preserved by [`wal_keep_segments`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-replication.html)
- (in 9.4) It's still needed by a replication slot.

If none of those apply, a `CHECKPOINT` (either automatic, or manually issued via SQL) will remove all WAL that's not currently required. So you don't have to delete it by hand.

In unusual circumstances you might need to use `pg_archivecleanup`, like if you've run out of disk space due to WAL accumulation after archiving has failed for a long time. You might decide to accept that you'll have to re-create your replicas as a result of throwing away WAL they still need and use `pg_archivecleanup` to free space to get the master running.

But you should never delete WAL segments by hand.

### Recovering with archived WAL

If you kept the archived WAL somewhere else, you might just be able to copy the files back into `pg_xlog`, or create a `recovery.conf` with a `restore_command` to do so. See the manual on PITR and log shipping for details.

### Recovering without archived WAL

If you don't have a copy of those WAL files somewhere else, you should restore from a backup if you have a recent backup, because you have corrupted your database.

If you do not have a backup, follow the instructions in the [corruption wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) and *only once you have made a complete copy of the current state of the database*, as a *last resort only*, use `pg_resetxlog` to throw away the transaction logs and force the DB to start with incomplete transactions.

You must then `pg_dump` the database, stop it, `initdb` a new one, and restore to it. Do *not* keep using the database you damaged. *Never* keep using a database you used `pg_resetxlog` on, and never use it except as a last resort.

Comment: Highly important is the last point about the very dangerous pg_resetxlog, which I have already seen in backup tools by 3rd party applications (!!).

Comment: @KookieMonster Please tell me their names so I can contact the vendors. That's bad.

Comment: They were told for sure :). As far as I know, they've changed it some time after. Surprising tough for a rather big company supporting PostgreSQL restores...

Comment: @CraigRinger You are a savior. This answer helped me a lot after I removed pg_xlog directory.

Comment: @NikunjSardhara Good news, it's been renamed to `pg_wal` in PostgreSQL 10, in the hopes that people won't delete it thinking its "just logs" anymore. Think that would've helped for you?

Comment: @CraigRinger I am on PostgreSQL 9.4, And i also thought that it must be some logs so I deleted it. But I had backup and then I used initdb, restored the backup and now everything is good as gold :D.